# Firefox WebExtension "browser is not defined" for Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have been trying to add local storage to a Firefox WebExtension I wrote. As a guide, I pulled the popular "[Favourite Colour](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/favourite-colour)" example from the webextensions-examples repository on GitHub.

However, my implementation *as well as the example* produce an error "ReferenceError: browser is not defined" in the console for the options page when loaded as a temporary add-on.

I thought the example might have an API issue since it didn't seem to work ("storage.managed colour: no value found"). However, I've checked the repository for other examples that use local storage with the same end.

Does local storage work with temporary add-ons? If not, what is the best way to test/develop add-ons with storage requirements?

Are there any good (working) examples of local storage that I could reference? Hopefully a working example will help me get some traction.

Many Thanks!

Edit: The code in [options.js](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/favourite-colour/options.js) lines 9 and 14 cause the error to be thrown.

line 9: 
    var storageItem = browser.storage.managed.get('colour');
line 14: 
    var gettingItem = browser.storage.sync.get('colour');

Comment: Could you include the specific bit of code that produces the error in the question, as well as how you define the options page in the manifest and how you open it?

Comment: @Xan I've updated the post with specific code.
The manifest for the example sets up the options page like so:
"options_ui": {
      "page": "options.html",
      "browser_style": true
},

Comment: When I opened the options page using the quick-access icon, the add-on didn't work. So, I opened the options.html document by dragging the local file into the browser and opened the console from there.

Comment: When you open a local file, it's not part of the extension, so `browser.*` APIs are not available. You need to solve the "didn't work" problem instead - so detail that.

Comment: @Xan Thank you - that makes sense. That helps me understand what I should have asked instead. How do I place "favourite-colour-examples@mozilla.org.json" in a location for it to be discovered by the extension? I assume the user isn't expected to do this manually.

Comment: You are looking at the _managed storage_ example. Manual overrides by organization admins in enterprise environment. No, users are never supposed to use `managed`, they use `local` and `sync` instead. If you have trouble working with these, take another read through docs and post a new question.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again @Xan!